# Inheritance in Java with array

Tags: java

I have a problem when I use inheritance and define an object of parent class then call the constructor from the child class which has its own properties. When i want to assign values to the child class using sets methods its gives me an error (cannot find symbol)
this is my code

```
    public class Shape {
private final double PI =3.14;
public Shape() {
}
public double getPI() {
    return PI;
} 
}

public class Rectangle extends Shape {
private double length;
private double width;
public Rectangle() {
}  
public double getLength() {
    return length;
}
public void setLength(double length) {
    this.length = length;
}
public double getWidth() {
    return width;
}
public void setWidth(double width) {
    this.width = width;
} 
}
public class Circle extends Shape{
private double radius;
public Circle(double radius) {
    this.radius = radius;
} 
public double getRadius() {
    return radius;
}
public void setRadius(double radius) {
    this.radius = radius;
}
```

}

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner in=new Scanner(System.in);
    Shape s[] = new Shape[3];
    int type;
    for (int i = 0; i < s.length; i++) {
         System.out.println("Enter the Shape:\n 1.Rectangle \n 2.Circle");
         type = in.nextInt();
         if(type==1){
             s[i] = new Rectangle();
             s[i].setLength(5.5);
         }  
    }
}
```

Comment: you need to declare it as an instance of the child class, if you declare it as an instance of the parent class, you are limited to the members of said parent class

Comment: Since you declared `Shape s[]` an element `s[i]` has the type `Shape`. The class `Shape` does not declare the method `setLength`.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem lies here:

```
s[i] = new Rectangle();
s[i].setLength(5.5);
```

Yes. You know that this form is an instance of `Rectangle`, all the JVM knows is that it's a `Shape`. If you want to use it as a `Rectangle`, you have to declare it as one:

```
Rectangle r = new Rectangle();
r.setLength(5.5);
s[i] = r;
```

EDIT: The reason for this is, when you declare an instance as a `Shape` (parent class), the JVM will consider it to be this, even if your code suggests (to a human reader) that a specific type will be used, the JVM will not make any assumptions on which sub class will be instantiated.
You are limited to the possibilities of the class you declared it to be.

Since you now again save it as a `Shape`, in your array, if later on you'll want to get that value, you'll need to cast it.

```
Rectangle rNew = (Rectangle)s[index]; // of course after checking whether it is in fact a Rectangle
```

Comment: and this is how you can check: `if(s[index] instanceOf Rectangle) `

Comment: *instanceof, not instanceOf. But, depending on whether or not Rectangle has subclasses as well, a s[index].getClass() == Rectangle.class would be better

Comment: Thank you for your help. but what if i want to declare 10 Shapes as array then the user decide for each element is it a Rectangle or Circle. then depends on user response he will input the value for that shape.  if(type==1){
                 s[i] = new Rectangle();
                 s[i].setLength(5.5);
             } else if(type ==2){
                 s[i]= new Circle();
             }

Comment: @JhonN just check my answer. the developer can still store both the Circles and the Rectangles in that array, since they are subclasses of Shape, but if you want to call the methods of the subclasses, you have to declare them as such.

Answer (score 0):

you `setLength()` method is present in your sub class `Rectangle` while `s[i]` points to an instance of type **Shape** which is a super class. thus, it doesn't recognize the instance method due to implicit upcasting. 
you will have to explicitly downcast you object `s[i]` from shape to Rectangle. 
This is how you can do it:

```
Rectangle r = (Rectangle)s[i];
r.setLength(5.5);
```

**NOTE**: Ofcourse the above statements gos after `s[i] = new Rectangle();`

an ideal way though (as explained by  @Stultuske):

```
Rectangle r = new Rectangle();
r.setLength(5.5);
s[i] = r;
```

Comment: which would throw a NPE, since s[i] would be null. There is no reason to downcast, since he just creates the Object there.

Comment: these statements are to go after `s[i] = new Rectangle();` ofcourse

Comment: @Stultuske I am just trying to explain about why the method is not accessible !!

Comment: if it's right after that statement, the downcast would be overkill. Why creating it as an Shape if you know you need it as a Rectangle?
Yes, I get that, but your solution shouldn't be this odd

Comment: cause Object-Oriented !!! you might wanna hold instances of Circle and Rectangle in the same list

Comment: @Stultuske I agree that you can rather avoid downcasting efforts. but my intent is purely to explain why the instance method is not accessible and how it can be !!

Comment: "cause Object-Oriented" .. ehm, ok? if you declare it as a Rectangle, it 'll still pass an IS-A of Shape, and you can still store it in the array, that's what inheritance does. And you can easily store Circles in there, too. You don't need (down)casting to explain any of that, and if you do want to explain the casting, why not explain it on a part where it would make sense?

Comment: @Stultuske my answer was for this `Why creating it as an Shape if you know you need it as a Rectangle?` it was never created as shape, but rather stored in an array holding pointers to Shape thus, implicitly upcasting it in the process as in the question.

Comment: there is NO list in the above code, only an array of Shapes. Whether you do "Shape a = new Rectangle(); s[i] = a;" or the above "s[i] = new Rectangle();" is exactly the same.

Comment: @Stultuske anyways, i upvoted your answer as its more complete with explanation.